# Open Source Java Report + Graph

Tags: java, graph, reporting

I would need some suggestion about open source framework to generate reports (pdf, doc) which contains graphs.

A long time ago I used JasperReport and I guess it is still alive, but no idea if right now there is better options.

It would be great if the framework supports changes easily in the report/graph format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Innovent Solutions has made some [reviews](http://www.innoventsolutions.com/open-source-reporting-review-birt-jasper-pentaho.html) about [Birt](http://www.innoventsolutions.com/birt-review.html) (Eclipse foundation), [JasperReports](http://www.innoventsolutions.com/jasper-review.html) and [Pentaho](http://www.innoventsolutions.com/pentaho-review.html) ([comparison matrix](http://www.innoventsolutions.com/birt-jasper-pentaho-comparison-matrix.html)). Maybe you can start there.

Answer (score 0):

Look into **Primefaces**. Its a JSF extended library. the flexibility I have seen in that library is unbelievable. very slick. combined with POJO, its real fast and very very powerful.

Ajax, jQuery, JS, HTML/CSS are part of it.

Look it up